# Triangle image with rounded corner css?

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface

I've attempt to make triangle with rounded corner using `skew` in `css` but i get result like this..

[image]

my css code is:

```
<style>
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:220px 40px;
    font:80% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}         
  
img{border:none;}

/* angled box styles */

.boxasli{
    height:200px;  
    width:200px;
    margin-top:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -ms-transform:skewX(-60deg); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:skewX(-60deg); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:skewX(-60deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:skewX(-60deg); /* Opera */
    transform:skewX(-60deg);
    
    -ms-transform:skewY(40deg); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:skewY(40deg); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:skewY(40deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:skewY(40deg); /* Opera */
    transform:skewY(40deg);
    
}
.boxasli img {
    height: 225px;
    width: 225px;
    
    -ms-transform:skewY(-20deg); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:skewY(-20deg); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:skewY(-20deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:skewY(-20deg); /* Opera */
    transform:skewY(-20deg);

    -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%; /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%; /* Firefox */
    -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%; /* Opera */
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

</style>
```

and html :

```
<div class="boxasli">
   <img src="images/portfolio/p02.jpg" alt="bike" />
</div>
```

I want to create image triangle shape like [image]

what should i change my `css`?or where can i achieve what i want with css or javascript,etc ?any link discuss about that?

please help.thanks..

Comment: You can achieve this using the css property `clip`. Here is an article on the subject. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Comment: what you want to do is not achievable using `border-radius`. And using `skew` is way off beam. `clip` may work for you depending on the browser support you need. Other than that, SVG might be a good solution.

Comment: here one my old dabblet forked : http://dabblet.com/gist/5855089 border-radius in action. code was not first meant to be rounded corners. it can be achive IMHO :)

Answer (score 0):

I would make a PNG image of the shape you need, in white working as a mask. Then have it in a DIV on top of your image.